# Wordpress database backup

Tags: mysql, wordpress, backup, wordpress-theming

does anyone know of a good way to automatically backup databases used for wordpress blogs? Preferably a way of getting the backup emailed as a .zip file to the admin user so they can be stored remotely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on this theme, the answers above have pointed me towards the following plugin:

http://www.genealogy-computer-tips.com/wp-database-backup/

This seems to be everything I needed! Cheers,

Answer (score 7):

http://codex.wordpress.org/Backing_Up_Your_Database

or use this plugin http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-db-backup/  I believe the plugin even has the email feature you are looking for.

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking for a manual method, you can do something like this:

```
mysqldump --opt -h'localhost' -u'YOURUSER' -p'YOURPASS' -PYOURPORT wordpress > backup.sql | tar -czf backup.tar.gz backup.sql
echo "Here's your backup" | mail your@email.com -a backup.tar.gz -s 'Wordpress backup'
```

This will tar.gz your backup and email it to you.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your hosting provider, you can run a `cron` job to connect to your MySQL instance, dump it with `mysqldump`, and mail (or more likely, `scp`) the result to you.  That will cover your entire database server (at least, assuming that you have one allocated to you and not just a single database).  That is what I did when I was hosted at NearlyFreeSpeech to back up all the blogs I had there for various people.  I do the same thing today for backing up blogs on my own server.